# Negating keypress in AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I'm playing a game and it acts wonky when I press 3 buttons at the same time. I need the resulting input of holding down "A S D" to be only "S".

Something like

```
#SingleInstance 
if getkeystate("a") 
if getkeystate("s") 
if getkeystate("d") 
    input "s"
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple, but perhaps not so short combination of hotkeys and their *up* variants will do the trick. This script works like you intended, but only with buttons `a` and `s`. When `s` is held down, `a` does nothing. When `s` is not held down, `a` acquires its previous state.

```
#SingleInstance, Force
SetBatchLines, -1

global a_down = false
global s_down = false

a::
    a_down = true 
    if( %s_down% = true )
        return
    Send, {a down}
return

a up::
    a_down = false
    if( %s_down% = true )
        return      
    Send, {a up}        
return

s::
    s_down = true
    if( %a_down% = true )
        Send, {a up}
    Send, {s down}
return 

s up::
    s_down = false
    if( %a_down% = true )
        Send, {a down}
    Send, {s up}
return
```

In the spirit of StackOverflow, I will not post the complete script that will work with all three keys. That is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

> I need the resulting input of holding down "A S D" to be only "S".

By "Input" you mean a `Send` command??  Please see [Beginner tutorial - hotkeys and hotstrings](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s2).

If your task would be to behave <kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> like <kbd>S</kbd>, you'd use

```
a & s::
    send s
return
```

But you're asking for three keys which needs some workaround

```
#if getKeyState("d")
a & s::
    send s
return
#if
```

or

```
a & s::
    if getkeystate("d")
    {
         send s
    }
return
```